# LINQ query to return from one table based on matching another table

Tags: c#, linq

I'm very novice with C# and LINQ and have been unable to design the query and/or code necessary.  I've researched here, Microsoft docs, C# in a Nutshell and have learned a lot but can't seem to apply it properly.

The data source is SQL Express, 5 small simple tables.  I wound up with a bit of a progressive design to clarify for myself.  I have MeetingDetail type that has a property int PartnerID, which is related to the Employees table Employee.ID -> MeetingDetail.PartnerID.  I want my new type to contain a property of the name of the partner based on this match.  The source properties are db.Employees.LastName and FirstName, both String type.

```
var filtered = db.MeetingDetails.Where(v => v.GroupID == ID);

var recentMeetingRowQuery = from meeting in filtered
select new
{
    Date = meeting.MeetingDate,
    Category = meeting.Category.Name,
    Partner = (db.Employees.Where(v => v.ID == meeting.PartnerID).Select(x => x.LastName))
};
```

It seems this is returning the wrong type for Partner property and I've tried ToString() in various ways.

[image]

Comment: `db.Employees.Where(v => v.ID == meeting.PartnerID)`

Comment: `v => ID == meeting.PartnerID` does not use `v` parameter for filtering

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Fabio!  I tried the code in the Partner = expression but the return type is Employee whereas I need a string from its properties.  I think.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyBerezovskiy.  I'm sorry but don't understand your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *join* to match records from two tables:

```
var recentMeetingRowQuery = 
       from meeting in db.MeetingDetails.Where(m => m.GroupID == ID)
       join employee in db.Employees on meeting.PartnerID equals employee.ID 
       select new {
           Date = meeting.MeetingDate,
           Category = meeting.Category.Name,
           Partner = employee.LastName
       };
```

Note: I assume you are using employee ID for matching and `v => ID == meeting.PartnerID` should actually be `v => v.ID == meeting.PartnerID`.

---

> It seems this is returning the wrong type for Partner property

Because `Select(x => x.LastName)` returns `IQueryable<string>`. You could select only first matched employee name by adding `.FirstOrDefault()` but join is more efficient solution.

Comment: your note about the comparison problem is accurate - it should be v.ID as you stated